# devenv ignoring breakpoints

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints, devenv

I have some issues with my Windows Forms UserControl and am unable to place it in a form. I'm trying to find the problem using design time debugging with devenv.exe but whatever I try, breakpoints are ignored. At first I had the "breakpoint will not be hit, no symbols for this document" warning but I fixed it and now there is no warning.

I know this has been answered may times, but none of these have worked for me and all out of options

- Enabling DEBUG constant
- Setting debug info to full
- Disabling Just my code
- Making sure the breakpoint is in the right place to be hit
- Making sure I use the debug option before launching
- Making sure I'm attached to the right process (there is only one available)
- Setting the project as startup
- Running VS as an administrator
- Disabling Step over properties and operators

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

Make sure that you used **Debug** configuration to debug your project.

**1)** reset vs settings under Tools-->Import and Export Settings--> reset vs settings

**2)** close Vs, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**Also**, Windows Forms UserControl project is a class library project, and it cannot set up to debug directly. You should create a console or windows form exe project and then reference the Windows Forms UserControl project, after that, initialize the class with `class_name xxx=new class_name();`, set a breakpoint on that. At last, set the new exe project as a startup project and then test it.

**3)** when you are debugging, please enter **Debug**-->**Windows**-->**Modules** and check if your `<user_control_project_name>.pdb` file is loaded, if not, you could right-click on it to **Load Symbols**.

Comment: My project is setup to launch devenv.exe aka Visual Studio to debug the designer, essentially Visual Studio debugging itself using another instance. My UserControl is a WinForms app project, not a library.

Comment: How did your command look like? Did you check if the Modules  window has the pdb file?

Comment: No command, just set the launch option to Executable and gave it the full path of devenv.exe